# How to delete the www folder from a cordova/phonegap project?

Tags: cordova, plugins

I have an iOS cordova/phonegap application. I dont want to use local html and javascript files , so i am loading the www folder on my server , where the phonegap app connects to.

After i do that all the javascript/html/css is loaded from the server.

However how can i delete the "www" folder from my project without getting an error?

I know i should do it through finder cause you cant delete the project from xCode , but even when i do so , when i run the project i get an error about the folder missing.

Has anyone ever tried to do so?

Comment: the error appears because your appdelegate creates a CordovaWebView Object, which tries to load resources from the www folder. Have a look in your AppDelegate Files.

Comment: Hmm thats a nice observation , but i cant really seem to be able to locate the object you are referring to. Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I was slightly wrong with the names:

in your Appdelegate.m, in the function

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

must be something like this

```
self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
self.viewController.view.frame = viewBounds;
```

as you can see, here it tries to load something from a "www" folder. The `self.viewController` is declared in the Appdelegate.h as such:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet PGViewController* viewController;
```

try removing the @"www" names for the wwwFoldername and see if it works

Comment: I see that this is for the phonegap-2.1.0 but for the phonegap/cordova-2.5.0 which is the latest this is not the case. I will try it though as i want to use both versions. Another question if you have an idea. In the latest version in order to load an external url , and not use the local "www" folder (thats why i want to delete it as i dont use it) you just put in the config.xml : <content src="http://this.is.myURL" />   Do you know how i could do the same in 2.1.0 where you have a .plist instead of the .xml ?